# MVC razor post model is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Probably missing something obvious here, but my model posted to the controller is always null... The model passes to the view correctly and I can access the properties, but when submitting the form, the model is null. Why?

Model...

```
public class ProfileModel
{

    public MembershipUser user { get; set; }
    public ProfileSettingsModel settings { get; set; }


}
```

Controller...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveSettings(ProfileModel model)
    {
        var x = model.user.UserName;
        return View();
    }
```

View...

```
 @model MyApp.Models.Profile.ProfileModel

 @using(Html.BeginForm("SaveSettings","Profile"))
    {

        //Tried removing these as I shouldn't need them, but no luck.
        @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.settings)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.user)

        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.settings.VisitorsCanAddMeAsFriend)
        @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.settings.VisitorsCanAddMeAsFriend, "Visitors can add me as a friend")
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.settings.VisitorsCanMessageMe)
        @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.settings.VisitorsCanMessageMe, "Visitors can message me")

         <button id="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>

     }
```

Rendered HTML...

```
<form action="/Profile/SaveSettings?HttpMethod=POST&amp;InsertionMode=Replace&amp;LoadingElementDuration=0&amp;AllowCache=False" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The VisitorsCanAddMeAsFriend field is required." id="settings_VisitorsCanAddMeAsFriend" name="settings.VisitorsCanAddMeAsFriend" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="settings.VisitorsCanAddMeAsFriend" type="hidden" value="false">
    <label for="settings_VisitorsCanAddMeAsFriend">Visitors can add me as a friend</label>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The VisitorsCanMessageMe field is required." id="settings_VisitorsCanMessageMe" name="settings.VisitorsCanMessageMe" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="settings.VisitorsCanMessageMe" type="hidden" value="false">
    <label for="settings_VisitorsCanMessageMe">Visitors can message me</label>                 
    <button id="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

Is there anything obvious?

Comment: Please post your **rendered** HTML.

Comment: You need to return your `ProfileModel`.

Comment: `@using(Html.BeginForm("SaveSettings","Profile"))` does not render the html you have shown (for the `form` tag). Show the real html.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke it is copied and pasted from the chrome debugger... the only bit not there is the @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.settings)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.user)

Comment: When you say the "model is null" do you literally mean the "model" variable of SaveSettings()?  Or do you mean model.user or model.settings?

Comment: Good question. Model.user and model.profilesettings are null.

Comment: You cant use `@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.settings)` because it would generate `<input name="settings" value="YourAssembly.ProfileSettingsModel" .../>` (a complex object cant be bound to a string so binding fails and `settings` will be `null`) so make sure both those are removed.

Comment: There is something odd going on if the html generated for the form tag is `action="/Profile/SaveSettings?HttpMethod=POST&amp;InsertionMode=Replace&amp;LoadingElementDuration=0&amp;AllowCache=False"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use MembershipUser in model binding.  Model binding requires that all properties have a public parameterless constructor, and MembershipUser's parameterless constructor is protected.  As such, you cannot use it directly.  You will need to create your own view model to pass the properties.

So, removing the settings and user HiddenFor's, then biding those properties directly will get you what you want.

Comment: Is there no way around this? I can pass the MembershipUser to the view and access its properties - it seems such a shame that I cannot update those properties unless I create a new model which is exactly the same apart from the constructor. :(

Comment: @Rich - You really shouldn't be doing this anyways.  MembershipUser contains properties you don't want exposed to the client.   For instance, an attacker could change the hidden for values through client-side tools and change their last logindate or whether they are approved or locked out.  These are internal structures you cannot simply accept the input of the client on.

Comment: thanks for the help. I think I understand this now. Thanks everyone for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.settings)
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.user)
```

To

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.user.UserName)
```

The default binder should at least pick that one up.

Comment: It did, but then complained that "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Comment: Model binding wont work if you don't have a parameterless constructor for your models. Post the models for `MembershipUser` and `ProfileSettingsModel`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - MembershipUser is most likely System.Web.Security.MembershipUser, which has a protected constructor so can't be used for model binding.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think you could do a html.hiddenfor (complex type), as the value has to represented as a string. In your render html you can see that then two HiddenFor's are not rendered as input type='hidden' ...../

So yes, the obvious error is the two html.hiddenfor. You will need to do a HiddenFor or each property that you wish to receive in the post

Answer (score 0):

In the controller's postback method, the last line says

```
return View();
```

but it should say

```
return View(model);
```

otherwise you are not passing the model back to the page.